# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to build unique file: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures Title image/jpeg Android 10(Samsung note 10+)

Tags: android, image, android-camera, illegalstateexception, android-10.0

I am using the below code to get image uri from camera

```
public static Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Comment: Do you have Storage permission?

Comment: Read and write permissions are there

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This came as an error only in android 10,earlier versions was working fine with this code.Any ways irrespective of the version I just changed the hardcoded "Title" in insertImage() to

```
public static Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, **"IMG_" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),** null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

Now its a tag with IMG_+time in long

Answer (score 17):

Yes, this error is only in Android 10, and only in some device models.

All images are being stored as "Title" but need a unique name.

The accepted answer is not always generating a unique name if you are trying to store multiple images at the same time.

So replace the `insertImage` call:

```java
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
    inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis(), null
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have Android 11 and It doesn't recognize the path when I upload the image from Camera.
I have solved this by

```
  Random rand = new Random();
          int randNo = rand.nextInt(1000);
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
    inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "IMG_" + randNo, null
);
```